# A simplistic video streaming container format

Tags: streaming, formats

I am currently working on a screen-sharing solution for an embedded system. Basically, I need to be able to see on my PC screen what happens on the device's display. I already have a solution that produces raw H264 frames which I can send over to the PC for presentation. I have experimented with the raw h264 stream format, but it does not allow me to detect the end of frame until the header for the next frame arrives. Since I only send frames in case anything is updated on the screen, there can be a substantial delay between separate frames. This means that the user will most likely see the one-before-last frame instead of the latest for an extended period of time.

I thought about using simple size prefix before each H264 frame, but such stream will be non-standard. For debugging ease (and user convenience) I would like to send stream that would be directly playable in major video player software (mplayer, vlc, etc.). Is there a simplistic but well-known video container format that is supported by major video players? It needs to be able to contain just a single H264 video stream (no audio or any other data, no further video streams). Ideally, I would like it to be simple enough to be able to implement the muxer myself without too much bother, as additional dependencies like ffmpeg are most unwelcome in the project.

Comment: For productive answers, the current and available A/V software stack on the device has to be known. Which AVC encoder are you using?

Comment: @Gyan My current solution uses libva (implementation of the VA API), and is roughly based on https://github.com/wayland-project/weston/blob/5.0/libweston/vaapi-recorder.c